# loadNibNamed loaded but class is ignored !

Tags: iphone, objective-c

NIB file is loaded successfully in my scrollView but sounds like it's class is totally ignored as if the xib is not associated with it, i checked that by accessing the class direct and its working fine showing all the NSLogs in viewDidLoad and UILable.text = @ ...etc.,

But after loading the same xib i can't see but a dead interface

Asking after a whole day of searching on this issue. Thanks in advance for you super guys

> Loading Nib by: ( in Setting.m )

```
NSArray *nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SettingProfile" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *settingA = [nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];
[ScrollView addSubview:settingA];
```

> SettingProfile.h

```
@class SettingProfile;
@interface Setting UIViewController {
SettingProfile *SettingProfile;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) SettingProfile *settingProfile;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are loading the Nib into a UIView which may not be the result you are looking for... I use the nib loading in my Table View... Perhaps this snippet will help you

```
OfferCell *cell = nil;

NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OfferCell" owner:self options:nil];
cell = (OfferCell*)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

I then do whatever I want with by cell.

Including add it to the tableView...

When I retrieve it I cast it into the OfferCell object again.

Comment: Thx Jason. No, I am loading the Nib into a scrollView, the thing is that i am loading a long UIView into UIScrollView.

Comment: I guess I didnt understand before. Perhaps tho, the approach you are taking is not the simplest solution. Are you trying to get a lot of information to Scroll, yet still be able to create the interface in interface builder ?

Comment: when I load items on a ScrollView, I put the scroll view in the base of the nib. Then I attach the "View" connector from my UIViewController and inside the viewDidLoad method i reset the frame with [scrollView setContentSize:];

Comment: Yes dear Jason, the reason behind this is that i have 3 long list of data, putting all of them in the same Nib is hard to edit n design, furthermore i want to learn this issue for future usage. It's easy for me to load a long UIView in a ScrollView within the one Nib.

Comment: Set the class of the "Files Owner" object to a Class you have. Then use that as your owner: param in loadNibNamed. The connections should be made to the owner.

Comment: Just perfect, many thanks Jason,, NSLogs working now, just needed to fix few IBOutlets things then i will post the code for others.

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved, to those whom facing the same problem just add the loaded Nib name in the owner:

```
NSArray *nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SettingProfile" owner:@"SettingProfile" options:nil];
UIView *gridView = [nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];
[ScrollView addSubview:gridView];
```

Still trying to connect the outlets in the loaded Nib/class correctly, i know connecting it with the same file owner is wrong causing app crash.